# Add a custom field type in solr

Tags: java, solr

In solr schema.xml many field types are defined.
for example

```
<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
```

is a definition for an integer field.

How  we define custom field types inside solr?

Is it possible to add java types such as BigInteger, BigDecimal, Map and other types as field type in solr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define new custom fields in solr by adding them to the `schema.xml` in the `<fields>` element:

```
<fields>
...
<field name="newfieldname" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
...
</fields>
```

To have an overview on the supported types (used to define the `<fieldType>` in Solr, which then are used to define the `field` elements), take a look to this link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr. For example, the `type` "text_general" is defined in schema.xml as:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

You can see it uses the `class="solr.TextField"` as its basic field type. The Solr schema already has several `types` defined by default... but you can define more, not sure if you can defined the ones you are asking for.

Comment: But can we add java types to the solr schema?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I do not think so. I think you need to "map" them to Solr data types, e.g.: "bigint" to "TrieLongField" when you are storing them in Solr... take a look into this info I found, mapping java (in this case it is SQL) data types to Solr: https://code.google.com/p/solr-jdbc/source/browse/trunk/solr-jdbc/src/main/java/com/google/code/solr_jdbc/value/DataType.java?r=94 probably you should go in these lines to develop your data types.

Answer (score 2):

You can define new fieldType by extending the [FieldType](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_4_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/FieldType.html) class where you can define your own analyzer for the field and also add other attributes. For example the [TextField](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/schema/TextField.html) is a subclass of the FieldType.